# Angular 4 - IE, Firefox 400 Bad Request

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, bad-request

I have angular 4 app that is working well in Chrome but IE and FF is showing 400 bad request, when I compare the http headers between IE and Chrome, I see IE, FF is adding additional headers. When I removed "If-Modified-Since: 0" header in Firefox and resend (thru FF developer tool) it  returns 200 OK. What could be the issue here and why IE/Firefox is failing and not chrome, it seems due to these cache headers.

Here are the IE Headers

```
GET {domain path}/assets/environments/environment.json HTTP/1.1
Referer: {host}/index.html
X-HttpWatch-RID: 45248-10892
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
If-Modified-Since: 0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: {host domain}
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1512081247.1492526215; _rollup=GA1.2.973698029.1530531199; ASP.NET_SessionId=jj12nlqxiugx24xj33m34anf;
```

Here are the Chrome headers (less numbers than IE)

```
GET {domain path}/assets/environments/environment.json HTTP/1.1
Host: {host domain}
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Referer: {host}/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: {value}
```